# Popping a negative number works but not for zero

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

In my code, I take a dictionary: {2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4:
'z', -3: 'z'} as a parameter and turn it into a list. I am supposed to print out letters (the value) by a certain amount, given by its key(integer), for example, the key pair 4: 'z' means that the letter z will be printed out 4 times. I specified that any key less than 1 should not be outputted at all, and it works for the key -3, but for some reason, the key 0 still appears despite me having specified to pop any integer key less than 1. This is what my output looks like at the moment:

```
1.
0. <--- This should be removed
2: ff
4: zzzz
```

But it should be like:

```
1.
2: ff
4: zzzz
```

The code:

```
def draw_rows(dictionary):
    turn_list = list(dictionary.keys())
    turn_list.sort()
    for num in turn_list:
        if num < 1:
            turn_list.pop(turn_list[num])
    for key in turn_list:
        print(key,": ", dictionary[key] * key, sep="")

def test_draw_rows():

    print("1.")
    draw_rows({2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4: 'z', -3: 'z'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you are popping the element from the list `turn_list`, which is a copy of list of dictionaries `turn_list = list(dictionary.keys())`,
 and popping an element from that list won't affect the original dictionary.

So you would want to pop the key in the original dictionary itself, by iterating over a copy of the dictionary, since you cannot update a dictionary while iterating over it

```
def draw_rows(dictionary):

    #Take copy of the dictionary
    dict_copy = dictionary.copy()

    #Iterate over the copy
    for key in dict_copy:
        #If key is less than 1, pop that key-value pair from dict
        if key < 1:
            dictionary.pop(key)

    #Print the dictionary
    for key in dictionary:
        print(key,": ", dictionary[key] * key, sep="")

def test_draw_rows():

    print("1.")
    draw_rows({2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4: 'z', -3: 'z'})

test_draw_rows()
```

You can also simplify your code via dictionary comprehension, where you make a new dictionary with `key > 1`

```
def draw_rows(dictionary):

    #Use dictionary comprehenstion to make a dictionary with keys > 1
    dictionary = {key:value for key, value in dictionary.items() if key > 0}

    #Print the dictionary
    for key in dictionary:
        print(key,": ", dictionary[key] * key, sep="")

def test_draw_rows():

    print("1.")
    draw_rows({2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4: 'z', -3: 'z'})

test_draw_rows()
```

The output in both cases will be

```
1.
2: ff
4: zzzz
```

If the aim is just printing, we can iterate over the keys, and print the necessary key and value pairs only.

```
def draw_rows(dictionary):

    #Iterate over dictionary
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        #Print only those k-v pairs which satisfy condition
        if not key < 1:
            print(key,": ", value * key, sep="")

def test_draw_rows():

    print("1.")
    draw_rows({2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4: 'z', -3: 'z'})

test_draw_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer more simpler code then the below code should work.

```
def draw_rows(dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k > 0:
            print(k, ':', v * k)

def test_draw_rows():
    print('1.')
    draw_rows({2: 'f', 0: 'x', 4: 'z', -3: 'z'})

test_draw_rows()
```

Output:

```
1.
2 : ff
4 : zzzz
```